# Add custom role to user subscriptions?

Tags: azure-stack

I am trying to create a custom role and add it to user subscriptions. The problem I am having is the values to put in the `AssignableScopes` value.  It works find if I use the Default Provider Subscription,

```
"AssignableScopes":[
       "/subscriptions/648532af-d660-4e85-9de3-5cc5f018a70c"
    ]
```

However, I was unable to determine how to also include user subscriptions.  However, if I try to use the `SubscriptionId` of a user subscription, it says it cannot find the subscription.  Using `Get-AzsUserSubscription` I can try to use the Id property,

```
    "AssignableScopes":[
       "/subscriptions/648532af-d660-4e85-9de3-5cc5f018a70c/providers/Microsoft.Subscriptions.Admin/subscriptions/2a77aee8-5716-4ab0-a2f3-34e72c3f7871"
    ]
```

but this errors out with

```
New-AzureRmRoleDefinition : Scope '/subscriptions/648532af-d660-4e85-9de3-5cc5f018a70c/providers/Microsoft.Subscriptions.Admin/subscriptions/2a77aee8-5716-4ab0-a2f3-34e72c3f7871' should 
begin with '/subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups'.
At line:1 char:1
```

The role I am trying to add is a custom role for NetBackup.  NetBackup requires access to backup VMs in user subscriptions.  I do not see this as a NetBackup question.

[Veritas NetBackup for Microsoft Azure Stack Administrator's Guide - Add Custom Role](https://www.veritas.com/content/support/en_US/doc/132560919-132584128-0/v133296876-132584128)

It it possible as an Azure Stack Administrator to add custom role definitions to user subscriptions?  What is the correct syntax for the items in `AssignableScopes` array?

Answer (score 0):

I think discovered the answer and it makes sense from a security point of view.  I have to login as a user with Owner rights of the target subscription and then I can add the role to the subscription.